# How to add button underneath image , is the way that I am appending elements correct or it can be done better

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am appending html dynamically but I am unable to add the button underneath the image (when I start a div or  a table the end tag is being closed automatically)

Relevant part of the js function :

```
var fullimage='<li class="picture'+i+'"> <img id='+filename+'  height="100" width="100" src='+this.result + ' /> </li>  '; 
var fullimage=fullimage+'<input type="button" id='+filename+' name="button2"  value="Set as default"> </input>';
$('.pictures').append(fullimage);
```

HTML

```
<h3>Primary picture</h3>
                    <div id="primary-pic">
                        <p>jpg, png or bmp files <br /> <span>(max 2mb)</span></p>
                        <div class="custom-input-file">
```

`

```
                                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
                            <!--    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="input-file" multiple="multiple" min="1" max"5"/> !-->
                                 <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="readURL(this);" size="1" class="input-file" />
                                Choose files

                                <body>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div id="more-pics">
                        <ul class="pictures">
                           <li class="picture1"> </li>
                            <li class="picture2">  </li>
                           <li class="picture3"> </li>
                            <li class="picture4">  </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div><!--/#more-pics-->`
```

The full js function that appends html can be found here :

http://pastebin.com/BJy6FtiU

Comment: Please post this as a jsfiddle then we can see the problem in action.

Comment: Well one error I can see is the input button. You've use an open and end tag where as it is more of a single tag (I don't do technical names :p) `<input type="button" value="hello" />`. What element is being closed by the function?

Comment: Beneto thanks for the input, I had a look at :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp it says that In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag.

In XHTML, the <input> tag must be properly closed, like this <input />.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the closing `LI` after the `input`.

You have:

```
<LI> <IMG> </LI> <INPUT>
```

But want:

```
<LI> <IMG><INPUT> </LI>
```

Also don't declare `var variableName` twice for the same variable.

```
var fullimage='<HTML>';
    fullimage +='<More HTML>";
```

Comment: Thanks , I have tried that previously but the buttons do not appear even though they are there (I can inspect them with firebug) maybe because I can see an image closing tag . so If I change the code to:var fullimage='<li class="picture'+i+'"> <img id='+filename+'  height="100" width="100" src='+this.result + ' ><input type="button" id='+filename+' name="button2"  value="Set as default"> </input> </img> </li>  '; 
 the resulting html is :

Comment: ul class="pictures">
<li class="picture2">
<img id="DSCN7874" width="100" height="100" src="data:">
<input id="DSCN7874" type="button" value="Set as default" name="button2">
</li>
</ul>

Comment: `input` has no closing tag..must use valid html

Comment: actually from what the Image tag <img>  can be a stand-alone unpaired tag.

Comment: `src` doesn't look right in what you just posted..  use console to inspect value of `this.result`

Comment: we are definitely writing the closing tag in the code per the first comment above for both input and image however its not being written in the actual source (maybe because of html rules because img and input are standalone elements)  regarding the this.result I haven't pasted the src string due to size.

Comment: disregard what you see in DOM. Browser doesn't use `/>` but there defintiely is no `</input>` closing tag when you write html

Comment: So you are saying that I don't need to use it is that right ? thank you

Comment: use what? I'm saying you need to validate your html and make sure value of `this.result` is what it should be

Comment: this.result has been validated, I thought you were saying not to use the input end tag.

Comment: correct there is no such thing as `</input>`. `input` is a self closing tag